# How to get and submit characters like letters with accents and 'ñ' in a Loopback 4 API

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, loopbackjs, encode

I have an API created in Loopback 4 which retrieves data from a database in PostgreSQL 13 encoded with UTF8. Visiting the API explorer (localhost:3000/explorer) and executing the GET requests I realize that even when the database fields contain characters like letters with accents and ñ's; the retrieved JSON only shows blanks in the position where the character must have appeared. For example, if the database has a field with a word like 'piña', the JSON returns 'pi a'.

When I try a POST request, inserting a field like 'ramírez' (note the **í**), in the database, the field is shown as 'ramφrez' and when I execute a GET of that entry, the JSON now has de correct value, 'ramírez'.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Buffer class:

```
var encodedString = Buffer.from('string', 'utf-8');
```

with this way you will be able to return anything you want. In NodeJS Buffer class already included so you don't need to install any dependencies.

If you don't get what you need you can change 'utf-8' part.

Comment: Using "import { Buffer } from 'buffer'" at top, the page doesn't load anymore. Console shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"

Comment: you don't need to import buffer at the top, you can use directly.
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers/